# wp_insert_post always returns 0 on one site, extensive testing done, can't get to the bottom

Tags: wp-insert-post, core

I have two sites. One, a fresh install, the other an existing site with errors/white screen of death on the `wp-admin/post-new.php` screen. I've disabled all of the active plugins, and enabled a default theme, and am still getting these errors (because the draft post is not created properly in the DB during the page load).

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'post_type' of non-object 
Warning: Creating default object from empty value
Notice: Trying to get property 'post_status' of non-object
Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object
```

I've tracked this down to an issue with `wp_insert_post()` when loading the `wp-admin/post-new.php` screen. For testing, I added a `wp_die( print_r( $wpdb ) );` in the `wp-includes/post.php` core file ([here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post.php#L4232)). This outputs a lot of information about the database query. No errors are present, and it says `[rows_affected] => 1, [insert_id] => 0,` and the return of `wp_insert_post()` is always 0.

I can't figure out why with a default core theme, no plugins active, no mu-plugins directory and no core files altered, `wp_insert_post()` is always returning 0. The post *is* inserted into the database, but it always has a post ID of 0 and the post-new.php screen white screens. When I have WP_DEBUG enabled, the above errors are present. I have a feeling it has to do with the one database, but I don't see any errors that would indicate so. Both DBs are InnoDB and pretty much identical except for the data held within them.

My very basic code to test `wp_insert_post()` is as follows, and as stated works on one site and not the other.

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => 'test',
    'post_content'  => '',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
);

// Insert the post into the database
$test = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

wp_die( 'New ID: ' . $test );
```

On the non-working site, the post is inserted into the database as post 0 and set to auto draft.

### Var Dump from Broken $wpdb

Here is the `var_dump` of the `$wpdb` return inside of `wp_insert_post()` in the core file linked above: https://pastebin.com/CGGv5q4N

As you can see there are no visible errors, and it looks like the post should have been assigned a post ID, because it's in the DB, but it's always post ID 0.

### Var Dump from Working $wpdb

https://pastebin.com/QTUVfdHR

Comment: help this url:-https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278136/wp-insert-post-is-returning-the-correct-post-id-no-failure-but-the-post-cont

Answer (score 0):

> I have a feeling it has to do with the one database, but I don't see
> any errors that would indicate so.

Yes, and apparently the structure of the WordPress posts table (`wp_040skcp8g2_posts`) in the problematic site is corrupted.

More specifically, *indexes such as the primary key are missing, so you need to add them back ASAP*:

- See line 26 at https://pastebin.com/CGGv5q4N which is `[Key] =>`  and should instead be `[Key] => PRI` and on line 28, it should be `[Extra] => auto_increment`.
- Try running `SHOW INDEXES FROM wp_040skcp8g2_posts` via phpMyAdmin and you'd notice the table indexes are missing.

And I don't know how come the indexes are gone, but I would scan the site for possible security loopholes and then ensure that WordPress core, plugins and themes are up-to-date. I might also change my WordPress/cPanel/FTP/SSH/etc. passwords.

> As you can see there are no visible errors, and it looks like the post
> should have been assigned a post ID, because it's in the DB, but it's
> always post ID 0.

The post ID field was supposed to be the *primary key with the value being **auto-incremented*** for every INSERT operation, but as I said above, the primary key is missing and the ID field is also no longer auto-incremented and therefore, the post ID always a 0, i.e. zero.

So you really need to fix the table structure and ensure the other (WordPress) tables have a good structure as well.

And for example, to add the primary key, you could do `ALTER TABLE wp_040skcp8g2_posts MODIFY ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)`.

However, if you need further assistance with that (adding back or fixing the indexes), try asking on https://dba.stackexchange.com/, or Stack Overflow? :)